# Schedule a Task-every 10 minutes: Fetch a URL 'https://site.com/folder/cron.php' fetched Status: 404 Output: File not found

Tags: php, cron

I'm a beginner, I've been looking for solutions on the net, but I haven't succeeded.

Fetch a URL: `https://site.com/folder/cron.php/`
I rented the server recently. OS Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS , Plesk Obsidian Version 18.0.32 I have a site.

The company does not offer support.

I have scheduled task a domain:

Fetch a URL: `https://site.com/folder/cron.php`

This URL (php script) works perfectly whith a browser.

But when i use the scheduled task, I have an error:

```
Task "https://site.com/folder/cron.php" completed with error in 0 seconds, output:

Url 'https://site.com/folder/cron.php' fetched
Status: 404
Output:
File not found.
```

The file is in:

`/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/folder/cron.php` (same: File not found)

I tried several commands found on the net, but also can't find the file (File not found)

On the server crontab file, I have:

A) In file for site: `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`, I have no Path. I don't think it's normal, do I?

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/opt/psa/tmp/sssY3Y4RF installed on Sun Jan 10 06:48:03 2021)
# (Cron version -- $Id: crontab.c,v 2.13 1994/01/17 03:20:37 vixie Exp $)
MAILTO=""
SHELL="/bin/sh"
10 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f '/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/_cron/cron.php'
```

B) In the file for root: `/etc/crontab`, I have:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user command
17 * * * * root cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6 * * * root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6 * * 7 root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6 1 * * root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

I read on the internet that it is good to add the command. in the root file.

Can someone help me please?

Ps: I have no experience. I searched the internet and found out more. I am an industrial programmer but I still know something from college .

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would recommend is to *never* manually edit the various crontab files on your computer unless you know *exactly* what you're doing. There's simply no need. This is also why the very first line in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` is `DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE`.

Second, the `10 * * * *` that you have means "run every hour at 10 minutes past the hour".

This is what you will need to do:

1. Restore your crontab files to what they were originally
2. Use `crontab` to set a new scheduled activity: `sudo crontab -e`
   **Note:** *You may be asked for your admin password*
3. Add the following line at the end of the file:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/wget --no-check-certificate -q "https://site.com/folder/cron.php" -O /root/cronout.txt
```

This is what's happening:

| Element | Action |
| --- | --- |
| `*/10 * * * *` | Run every 10 minutes, every hour, every day, every week, every month |
| `/usr/bin/wget` | Use `wget` to call the `PHP` file |
| `--no-check-certificate` | Ignore the SSL certificate check (optional) |
| `-q` | Operate "quietly", not outputting all the usual status info |
| The URL | What to get |
| `-O` | Output to a file |
| `/root/cronout.txt` | The file to record the output to. If you do not want to keep the most current output, you can replace `/root/cronout.txt` with `/dev/null` |

This should do what you need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and thank you for your answers and help....

Ps: Maybe can help another like me who have their own server.

I have OS
Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Product
Plesk Obsidian
Version 18.0.32

Maybe on others it's different. The answer is very simple, once you find the solution :))

My site assigned to 2 IPs but domain resolves to 1 IP only

I disabled record in /etc/hosts:
#2a01:4f8:121:338::2 site.com site....

and work superrrrr

Thanks a lot and have a nice day !

Comment: Is this what solved your original problem? It's not clear to me how it's related...

Comment: Hi -Zanna. Yes, that was the solution to the initial problem and it works perfectly cron. The cause I said above, in my case with the 2 IPs. I tried other similar commands in scheduled taskand work super. I said, in the case of my server.